# how to check timestamp in h2 database

Tags: sql, timestamp, h2

need to check date value in h2 database.
I'm using as below. but it is giving error.

```
where lim.REVIEW_DATE >= TIMESTAMP  20220606
```

Please suggest the correct syntax

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use standard literals:

[`DATE '2022-06-06'`](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#date) for values of `DATE` data type.

[`TIMESTAMP '2022-06-06 00:00:00'`](https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#timestamp) for values of `TIMESTAMP` data type.